# Oracle : ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, ora-00933

I'm running into an oracle error,

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

With the follwing.

```
insert into TableOne (name, description, scopeid, readonly)
Select 'access', 'Some Description', 0, 0 from dual
where not exists(SELECT * FROM Privilege WHERE name = 'access')
/
insert into TableTwo (name, uuid, description, scopeid) 
Select 'Role','ROLE_UUID','Another description.', 0 from dual
where not exists(SELECT * FROM Role WHERE uuid = 'ROLE_UUID')
/
```

I have added semicolons at the end of each statement before the '/'.

Any suggestions where I may be wrong?

Comment: The code you posted wouldn't throw that error. Instead, the second `insert` **will** throw a *different* error. You are only giving three values for four columns. You will get ORA-00947, "not enough values". Is that the EXACT code and the ONLY code that you are running? (How do you know the error doesn't come from something else?)

Comment: When I went to remove any sensitive names/description I flubbed the 2nd parameter on the second query (Good Catch). Its there and the error I receive is the one in the description. I know the error is coming from the first query because we have a build process that is processing other files until it gets to the one with this query at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post `CREATE TABLE` statements so I did that myself.

```
SQL> create table privilege as
  2    select 'some name' name from dual;

Table created.

SQL> create table role as
  2    select 'some UUID' uuid from dual;

Table created.

SQL> create table tableone
  2    (name        varchar2(10),
  3     description varchar2(20),
  4     scopeid     number,
  5     readonly    number);

Table created.

SQL> create table tabletwo
  2    (name        varchar2(10),
  3     uuid        varchar2(10),
  4     description varchar2(20),
  5     scopeid     number);

Table created.

SQL>
```

Let's run `insert` statements you posted as exact copy/paste (I didn't change anything):

```
SQL> insert into TableOne (name, description, scopeid, readonly)
  2  Select 'access', 'Some Description', 0, 0 from dual
  3  where not exists(SELECT * FROM Privilege WHERE name = 'access')
  4  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into TableTwo (name, uuid, description, scopeid)
  2  Select 'Role','ROLE_UUID','Another description.', 0 from dual
  3  where not exists(SELECT * FROM Role WHERE uuid = 'ROLE_UUID')
  4  /

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Apparently, both of them work and no `ORA-00933` (*SQL command not properly ended*) is raised. Therefore, either you didn't post everything you should have, or you're misinterpreting reality.

Comment: I guess it fair to assume the tables did not exists. But they did. We are running these queries in an automated build. Your solution is 'correct' but in my case I had to remove an extra space between a 3rd statement that I though was largely irrelevant and that got it to work. Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: You're welcome. As of removing "extra space": well, there's none in code you posted so it was *impossible* for the community to guess what you did wrong. Because, as demonstrated, that code *works*. OK, never mind, I'm glad you fixed it.